# Is there a way to enable all the block supports for an ACF Block?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gutenberg-blocks

```
{
    "name": "acf/testimonial",
    "title": "Testimonial",
    "description": "A custom testimonial block.",
    "style": [ "file:./testimonial.css" ],
    "category": "formatting",
    "icon": "admin-comments",
    "keywords": ["testimonial", "quote"],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "preview",
        "renderTemplate": "testimonial.php"
    },
    "supports": {
        "align": true,
        "spacing": true,
        "color": true,
        "alignContent": "matrix"
    }
}
```

My block.json is above. I would like to be able to enable all the core editor supports for a block.

I have been on google all day trying to find an add all option or enable all and have had no luck Any help is appreciated!